# Using template in a map

Tags: java

I am writing a function called `arrayToMap()`.  I was originally going to just allow `String` arrays, but I thought I could make it generic so any type of array.  I tried the following code snippet but it tells me `T` cannot be resolved to a type:

```
public Map <T, Integer> arrayToMap( T [] arr ) {    
    assert( arr != null ) : "arrayToMap null array";
    Map<T,Integer> res = new HashMap<>();
    int ind = 0;
    for ( T val: arr ) {
        res.put(val, ind);
        ind++;
    }   
    return res;
}
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 7):

The signature should be changed to this:

```
// Notice the <T>, this is a generic method declaration
public <T> Map <T, Integer> arrayToMap( T [] arr )
```

This is called a *generic method* and you can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). Just like generic type declarations (classes and interfaces), method declarations can also be generic which means that they can be parameterized by one or more type parameters such as the `<T>` in the example above.

However, if your class is a *generic class* i.e. it is declared as a generic type the signature can stay the same as in the original example.

```
// A generic type declaration <T>
public class MyClass<T> {

    // The type T comes from the generic type declaration,
    // therefore the generic method declaration is not needed
    public Map<T, Integer> arrayToMap(T [] arr) {
       ...
    }
}
```

But, a *generic class* is likely not a good approach for the OP:s original use case since the `arrayToMap` method kind of implies that it is a general method that can be used on any type of array.